# Show $f(1/n)\to(1/(n-2))$ is bijective

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The original question is how to define a bijection between $(0,1)$ and $[0,1]$.

HOWEVER, please notice that the I understand the general proof. I just cannot figure out how to prove that $f(1/n)=1/(n-2)$ is bijective; injection part is easy to prove but how to prove surjection? $n\to n-2$ mapping is bijection reasoning is not rigorous enough, IMO.

I thought I would need to set up something like $y=1/(n-2)$ here which doesnt work.

Proof: 
general idea is $A=\{1/2, 1/3,...\}\cup{0}$
$$f(x)=x \text{ for } (0,1)\setminus A$$
$$f(1/2)=1, f(1/3)=0 \text{ and } f(1/n)=1/(n-2) \text{ for } A$$

Comment: Please check my edit. I was not sure what you meant with $\A$.

Comment: sorry backslash here means - (set difference)

Comment: @MrYouMath You should probably not just assume that it will be all good by just throwing in some dollars. Normally you would need to actually insert appropriate MathJAX markup as well - otherwise there is a risk that the edit does more harm than good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle the cases in the definition, you have to consider the function on the whole $(0,1)$.

To see that it's onto you pick an $y\in [0,1]$. Either it's $0$ and we have $f(1/3)=0$, or it's $1=f(1/2)$ or it can be written as $1/k$ in which case $f(1/(k+2)) = 1/k=y$ or it's some other number not in $A$ which means that $f(y)=y$.

You use the similar technique, but you have to consider cases once more to show injectivity. You use the solutions to $f(x)=y$ and show that they are the only solutions. That is if $f(x)=y=f(\xi)$ then $\xi=x$.

For example if $y=0$ and we have $f(\xi)=0$. Now either $\xi\notin A$ which means $f(\xi)=\xi=y=0\in A$ (contradiction), or $\xi=1/k$ for some integer $k>3$ in which case $f(\xi) = f(1/k) = 1/(k-2) \ne 0=y$ (contradiction), or $xi = 1/2$ which means $f(\xi)=1\ne 0=y$ (contradiction) or $\xi=1/3$ which we know is a solution. So we can conclude then that necesarily $\xi=1/3$.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer; however, "For any integer l>1 we have that k=l+2>3 would make f(1/k) map to 1/l." that is where i am confused; if a function is f(n)=n-2, then y=n-2 --> n=y+2 --> f(y+2)=y would prove surjection. Here, I would need to set it up as y=1/(n-2); why can you just set  up the denominator rather than the whole 1/(n-2)?

Comment: or is this something related to the definition of surjection I missed?

Comment: @jamesFifa It means that there's a $k>3$ such that $f(1/k)$ maps to $1/l$. Which means that $f_R(R) = \{1/l: l\in\mathbb Z_{>1}\}$. Of course for completeness you should also prove that if $k>3$ then $f(1/k)$ can be written as $1/l$ for some integer $l>1$.

Comment: @jamesFifa The proof relies on the fact that if you partition the domain and the restrictions of the function to the components are injective and the images of the component forms a partition of the codomain then the function is bijective.

Comment: Do you mean for completeness, I have to prove that every element of the infinite set of f(1/k) can be written in the form of 1/l, not just l like usual cases? Can you give me some insight on that? Is it another argument like g(1/l)=l, and set m=1/l, so on?

Comment: @jamesFifa I've rewritten the answer - I think my first way of trying to answer may have been a bit too abstract. And still I've left a piece of the proof out, but I think it should be quite straight forward to continue along that approach on your own.

Answer (score 0):

You can take $\frac{1}{n}$ in $[0,1]$ and send it bijectively to $\frac{1}{n+1}$ to show that $|[0,1]|=|[0,1)|$ then act simmetrically or do the same with $1-\frac{1}{n}$ and $1-\frac{1}{n+1}$

Comment: i am sorry but i do not quite understand...can you elaborate a little bit?

Comment: Ok. Here the only fact to care about is that if $X$ is an infinite set (in the sense thar it contains a sequence) and $x\in X$ then you can write a bijection from $X$ to $X-\{x\}$. Then, you can apply twice the idea and drop the $0$ and the $1$ away from $[0,1]$.